# Constructor not visible

Tags: java, android, overriding

I am developing an Android application which makes use of the [`ScanResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html) object. This object is in the form of:

```
[SSID: __mynetwork__, BSSID: 00:0e:2e:ae:4e:85, capabilities: [WPA-PSK-TKIP][ESS], level: -69, frequency: 2457, timestamp: 117455824743]
```

I am trying to override the `equals()` method of this class by creating my own class which extends `ScanResult`:

```
public class MyScanResult extends ScanResult {

    public MyScanResult() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (!(o instanceof ScanResult))
            return false;

        ScanResult obj = (ScanResult) obj;
        if (!BSSID.equals(obj.BSSID))
            return false;
        if (!SSID.equals(obj.SSID))
            return false;
        if (!capabilities.equals(obj.capabilities))
            return false;
        if (frequency != obj.frequency)
            return false;
        if (level != obj.level)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

}
```

However when I try this, I get the following error: `The constructor ScanResult() is not visible`. How can I solve this please?

Answer (score 5):

The public constructor signature for `ScanResult` is:

```
public ScanResult(String SSID, String BSSID, String caps, int level, int frequency)
```

You need to invoke the super class with matching parameters

Comment: `The constructor ScanResult(String, String, String, int, int) is undefined`

Comment: This is the [source of ScanResult](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.java). If you're using Eclipse, do CTRL+SPACE and verify that you are matching the superclass parameters

Comment: I did that. My ScanResult class has the following constructor: `ScanResult();`. The problem is that it is not public

Comment: `android.net.wifi.ScanResult` doesn't have any default constructor, private or otherwise. Are you using the current version?

Comment: Yes, I have the latest SDK

Comment: This is a long shot - there isnt another class called `ScanResult` in your classpath?

Comment: The class that you are referencing does not match the current version with the above signature. Try cleaning your project. Ensure that you are referencing `android.net.wifi.ScanResult`

Comment: I created a new project from scratch and added just the above class which references `android.net.wifi.ScanResult` but no luck

Answer (score 0):

**The apparently good way**:

`ScanResult` expects parameters:

```
public ScanResult(  String SSID, 
                    String BSSID,
                    String caps,
                    int level,
                    int frequency)
```

You can check the class definition [here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-frameworks-base/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.java.htm)

**The ugly way**:

As you say, apparently `ScanResult` is private. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5593430/616225) tells you to use reflection to get to the constructor.

**The possibly only way**:

Nobody knows how this happens to you (it's actually weird). But there's a change to solve it. Hit the [here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-frameworks-base/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.java.htm) link, copy the class into your project (change its package for yours, of course), and just make `MyScanResult` inherit from this one. Android is open source, and, despite this class may change in the future, you ensure this will work right now. Then, you can try casting your new `ScanResult` using `(android.net.wifi.ScanResult)scanResult`, if you need the primitive class.

Comment: `The constructor ScanResult(String, String, String, int, int) is undefined`

Comment: Which `ScanResult` are you using? Are you using `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.model.ScanResult`?

Comment: `android.net.wifi.ScanResult`

Comment: Ok, the last chance, check my second (hopefully not) or third solution.