# The constructor BaseEncoding() is not visible when extending Guava libraries

Tags: java, constructor

There are different questions already available related to this error, but none is realted to this specific class i.e [BaseEncoding](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.html)

When i am extending `BaseEncoding` on my class, I am getting this error,

> The constructor BaseEncoding() is not visible

here is the code,

```
import com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding;

public class TheRace extends BaseEncoding{

    public TheRace() {
        super();
    }
}
```

from this answer, [Constructor not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886514/constructor-not-visible)

I understand that `BaseEncoding()` constructor must be expecting some parameters, but when I visit its official documentation, there is no constructor defined.

How can I pass the parameters to solve my issue when there is no parametrized constructor in the `BaseEncoding` class  ?

Comment: `BaseEncoding` is abstract and simply doesn't define a constructor.

Comment: why do you need constructor? most likely you are supposed to use factory methods like http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.html#base16()

Comment: You should tell us what you're trying to achieve here, why do you need to extends `BaseEncoding`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BaseEncoding` isn't meant to be subclassed; its constructor is deliberately made `private` and not visible outside the class.  You're supposed to acquire instances of it using its factory methods like `base16()`.

Answer (score 0):

`BaseEncoding` is an [abstract class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html). It cannot be instantiated! Therefore defining a constructor isn't necessary (Although [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28222723/the-constructor-baseencoding-is-not-visible-when-extending-guava-libraries#comment44808760_28222878)).

In order to acquire (static) objects of type `BaseEncoding`, the class does define some factory methods (e.g., BaseEncoding.[base16()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.html#base16%28%29)).