# AspectJ - Use reflection to instanciate object of not public class

Tags: java, reflection, aspectj

I am trying to instanciate an object of a non public class in AspectJ.

I have this class:

```java
package ca1.business;

public class Bill {

    int id;
    String idOperator;
    String idClient;

    Bill(int id, String idOperator, String idClient) { /* (...) */ }
    public String toString() { /* (...) */ }
    public boolean equals(Object o) { /* (...) */ }
    public int getId() { /* (...) */ }
    public String getOperator() { /* (...) */ }
    public String getClient() { /* (...) */ }
}
```

In the aspects class I wanted to be able to do:

```java
Bill b = new Bill(currInvoice, idOperator, idClient);
```

The problem is that I get an error:

```
The constructor Bill(int, String, String) is not visible
```

So I investigated and tried to use reflection like it's explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560451/mocking-up-wifimanager-for-android-unit-testing/5593430#5593430) post.

```java
try {
    Constructor<Bill> cons = Bill.class.getDeclaredConstructor(null);
    cons.setAccessible(true);
    Bill invoice = cons.newInstance(null);
    invoice.id = 1;
    invoice.idOperator = "foo";
    invoice.idClient = "bar";
    // etc...
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InstantiationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But I get an error in the lines:

```java
invoice.id = 1;
invoice.idOperator = "foo";
invoice.idClient = "bar";
```

The error is:

```
The field Bill.X is not visible.
```

Does anyone know if there is any workaround?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that **includes** your aspectj sources.

Comment: In class Bill you have a package-private constructor - it is not visible from another package, so make it public and call Bill b = new Bill(currInvoice, idOperator, idClient); without reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use reflection?

Let us assume the `Bill` class looks like this:

```java
package ca1.business;

public class Bill {
  int id;
  String idOperator;
  String idClient;

  Bill(int id, String idOperator, String idClient) {
    this.id = id;
    this.idOperator = idOperator;
    this.idClient = idClient;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Bill [id=" + id + ", idOperator=" + idOperator + ", idClient=" + idClient + "]";
  }

  public static Bill instance;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(instance);
  }
}
```

We want our aspect to populate the static member before `main` is executed (silly example, just for demo):

**Option A: privileged aspect**

```
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import ca1.business.Bill;

public privileged aspect MyAspect {
  before() : execution(public static void main(String[])) {
    Bill.instance = new Bill(11, "operator", "client");
  }
}
```

**Option B: put aspect into package `ca1.business`**

The constructor is package-private, i.e. other classes in the same package can access it.

```java
package ca1.business;

public aspect MyAspect {
  before() : execution(public static void main(String[])) {
    Bill.instance = new Bill(11, "operator", "client");
  }
}
```

**Option C: put factory class into protected package as a helper**

```java
package ca1.business;

public class BillFactory {
  public static Bill create(int id, String idOperator, String idClient) {
    return new Bill(id, idOperator, idClient);
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import ca1.business.Bill;
import ca1.business.BillFactory;;

public aspect MyAspect {
  before() : execution(public static void main(String[])) {
    Bill.instance = BillFactory.create(11, "operator", "client");
  }
}
```

**Console log for each option A, B, C**

```
Bill [id=11, idOperator=operator, idClient=client]
```